# Defining a map with custom comparator where the value datastructure also has custom comparator

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, stl

I wanted to define a datastructure like:

```
struct node {
    int x_coordinate;
    int y_coordinate;
    // some variables
};

map<node, priority_queue<node> > M;
// or lets say 
map<node, set<node> > M
```

The problem I am facing is I don't know how to write it's custom comparator

Also do you think if it is possible to sort the priority_queue based on the distance from the it's key node. For example let's say if I have key node with x_coordinate=0 and y_coordinate=0, and I want to insert (8,6),(4,3),(15, 9),(0,1).

So priority_queue would be something like (0,1) (4,3) (8,6) (15,9)

P.S. : I have used following code after discussion with people but it's still giving compilation error

```
struct Node {
    Node (int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    int x, y;
};

struct cmp {
    Node node(0,0); // this node corresponds to the node that came from map key
    cmp(Node node) {
        this->node = node;
    }
    int getDistance (Node a, Node b) {
        return abs(a.x - b.x) + abs(a.y - b.y);
    }
    bool operator () (Node node1, Node node2) {
        return (getDistance(node, node1) < getDistance(node, node2));
    }

};

int main() {
    auto mapCmp = [&] (Node node1, Node node2){
        return node1.x < node2.x and (node1.x == node2.x and node1.y < node2.y);
    };
    map<Node, priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, cmp(Node)>, decltype(mapCmp)> myMap(mapCmp);
    myMap[Node(0,0)].push(Node(2,4));
    myMap[Node(0,0)].push(Node(1,3));
    myMap[Node(0,1)].push(Node(2,4));
    myMap[Node(0,1)].push(Node(1,3));
    return 0;
}
```

Error Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: something like this:
bool cmp (node a, node b) {
    return a.x < b.x or (a.x == b.x and a.y < b.y);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem. The latter portion (priority order based on the mapped-from key value) presents the real challenge.

**Map Custom Key Comparison**

The basic three methods from key comparison to a map are:

- Provide an `operator <` member override for the map key type, OR
- Provide a functor type as the comparator for the map, OR
- Provide a free-function.

The most common of these is the first, simply because it's the easiest to implement and visualize. The default comparator for a map is `std::less<K>` where `K` is the key type. The standard library `std::less` defaults to attempt an `operator <` comparison, in effect it does this:

```
bool isLess = (a < b)
```

where `a` and `b` are both your key type. Therefore, a simple member const `operator <` overload will fit the requirements and get you what you want:

```
struct Node {
    Node(int a=0, int b=0)
        : x(a), y(b)
    {
    }

    int x, y;

    // called by default std::less
    bool operator <(const Node& rhs) const
    {
        return (x < rhs.x) || (!(rhs.x < x) && y < rhs.y);
    }
    
    // simple distance calculation between two points in 2D space.
    double distanceFrom(Node const& node) const
    {
        return std::sqrt(std::pow((x - node.x), 2.0) + std::pow((y - node.y), 2.0));
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Node const& node)
    {
        return os << '(' << node.x << ',' << node.y << ')';
    }
};
```

This supports a strict weak order and will suffice. The other options are a little bit more complicated, but not by much. I'll not cover them here, but there are pleny of questions on SO that will.

Note: I added the `distanceFrom` and `operator <<` members and friend for later use in the final sample; you'll see them later.

---

**Priority Queue Instance Comparison Override**

Never done this before, but if there is an easier way I'm certainly open to suggestion. The problem with using a template-type comparator override for your priority queue is you can't really do it. You want each queue to be ordered based on distance to origin, where the origin is the map key for that queue. That means each *comparison* object must somehow be fed the origin of the  map key, and you can't do that with a template-type override (i.e. a compile-time thing).

What you *can* do, however, is provide an *instance* comparison override. `std::priority_queue` allows you to provide a custom comparison object *where the queue is created* (in our case, when it is inserted into the map as the mapped-to target). A little massaging and we come up with this:

First, a priority functor that takes either no args or a Node.

```
// instance-override type
struct NodePriority
{
    NodePriority() = default;

    NodePriority(Node node)
        : key(std::move(node))
    {
    }

    // compares distance to key of two nodes. We want these in
    // reverse order because smaller means closer means higher priority.
    bool operator()(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) const
    {
        return rhs.distanceFrom(key) < lhs.distanceFrom(key);
    }

private:
    Node key;
};

using NodeQueue = std::priority_queue<Node, std::deque<Node>, NodePriority>;
```

The `using NodeQueue` will save us a ton of typing in the sample that follows.

**Sample**

Using the above we are now ready to build our map and queue. The following creates a random list of ten nodes, each of which carry and x,y in the range of 1..9. We then use those nodes to build ten priority queues, one for each map entry we're creating. The map entries are the diagonal slice (i.e. (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), etc.). With the same the same ten random elements we should see different priority queue orderings as we report the final results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <random>

struct Node {
    Node(int a=0, int b=0)
        : x(a), y(b)
    {
    }

    int x, y;

    // called by default std::less
    bool operator <(const Node& rhs) const
    {
        return (x < rhs.x) || (!(rhs.x < x) && y < rhs.y);
    }

    // simple distance calculation between two points in 2D space.
    double distanceFrom(Node const& node) const
    {
        return std::sqrt(std::pow((x - node.x), 2.0) + std::pow((y - node.y), 2.0));
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Node const& node)
    {
        return os << '(' << node.x << ',' << node.y << ')';
    }
};

// instance-override type
struct NodePriority: public std::less<Node>
{
    NodePriority() = default;

    NodePriority(Node node)
        : key(std::move(node))
    {
    }

    // compares distance to key of two nodes. We want these in
    // reverse order because smaller means closer means higher priority.
    bool operator()(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) const
    {
        return rhs.distanceFrom(key) < lhs.distanceFrom(key);
    }

private:
    Node key;
};

using NodeQueue = std::priority_queue<Node, std::deque<Node>, NodePriority>;

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng{ 42 }; // replace with  { std::random_device{}() } for random sequencing;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 9);

    std::map<Node, NodeQueue> myMap;

    // generate ten random points
    std::vector<Node> pts;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        pts.emplace_back(Node(dist(rng), dist(rng)));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        Node node(i, i);
        myMap.insert(std::make_pair(node, NodeQueue(NodePriority(node))));
        for (auto const& pt : pts)
            myMap[node].emplace(pt);
    }

    // enumerate the map of nodes and their kids
    for (auto& pr : myMap)
    {
        std::cout << pr.first << " : {";
        if (!pr.second.empty())
        {
            std::cout << pr.second.top();
            pr.second.pop();
            while (!pr.second.empty())
            {
                std::cout << ',' << pr.second.top();
                pr.second.pop();
            }
        }
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }
}
```

Note: the pseudo random generator is always seeded with `42` to have a repeatable sequence. When you decide to turn this loose with non-repeatable testing just replace that seed with the one provided in the comment next to the declaration.

**Output** (yours will vary, of course).

```
(0,0) : {(3,1),(5,1),(3,5),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(1,9),(6,7),(5,8),(6,8)}
(1,1) : {(3,1),(5,1),(3,5),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(6,7),(1,9),(5,8),(6,8)}
(2,2) : {(3,1),(3,5),(5,1),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(6,7),(5,8),(1,9),(6,8)}
(3,3) : {(3,1),(3,5),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(5,1),(6,7),(5,8),(6,8),(1,9)}
(4,4) : {(5,4),(5,5),(3,5),(5,3),(5,1),(3,1),(6,7),(5,8),(6,8),(1,9)}
(5,5) : {(5,5),(5,4),(3,5),(5,3),(6,7),(5,8),(6,8),(5,1),(3,1),(1,9)}
(6,6) : {(6,7),(5,5),(6,8),(5,4),(5,8),(3,5),(5,3),(5,1),(1,9),(3,1)}
(7,7) : {(6,7),(6,8),(5,8),(5,5),(5,4),(3,5),(5,3),(1,9),(5,1),(3,1)}
(8,8) : {(6,8),(6,7),(5,8),(5,5),(5,4),(3,5),(5,3),(1,9),(5,1),(3,1)}
(9,9) : {(6,8),(6,7),(5,8),(5,5),(5,4),(3,5),(5,3),(1,9),(5,1),(3,1)}
```

I'l leave you to verify the accuracy of the distanceFrom calculations, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct cmp {
    cmp(Node node) { this->node = node; }
    bool operator () (const Node& node1, const Node& node2) {
        return (getDistance(node, node1) < getDistance(node, node2));
    }

    Node node; // this node corresponds to the node that came from map key
};
```

You can declare map as

```
std::map<Node, priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, cmp(Node)>> myMap;
```

The below line makes the above written comparator different from regular comparators because you want to pass the key of the map inside the comparator.

```
    cmp(Node node) { this->node = node; }
```

I have not compiled the above. If any errors should work with trivial fix. I think I have given enough code to unblock you. As an exercise, try using lambda instead of a separate comparator function.

Comment: I wrote it as you said but it's still giving some errors, can you please help me with this, I have also added the map comparator which I think works fine but the comparator for priority_queue is giving me troubles

Comment: This won't compile because `cmp(Node)`, the third template argument to `myMap` is not a *type*. This can be rectified using an instance-override when constructing the priority queue being inserted into the map. A little more work, but I think doable.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to give how to do it. Giving full compilable stuff doesn't help much with learning. So I said if any errors, it should work with trivial fix. In the process of fixing the compilation errors, one learns a lot.